# Custom NSFastEnumeration method?

Tags: objective-c, containers, nsfastenumeration

I Have a container class which stores its data in a dictionary

I would like to enumerate the objects and not the keys.

right now I have code like this

```
-(NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(__unsafe_unretained id [])buffer count:(NSUInteger)len
{
    return [self.container countByEnumeratingWithState:state objects:buffer count:len]; // this isn't working as container is dictionary
}

-(myobject *)objectAtIndex:(int)number // this is the method to retrieve a specific object
{
    int i = 0;
    for(id key in self.container) {
        if (number == i) {
            id value = [self.container objectForKey:key];
            return value;
        }
        else i++;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the `-allValues` property like this:

```
-(NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(__unsafe_unretained id [])buffer count:(NSUInteger)len
{
    return [self.container.allValues countByEnumeratingWithState:state objects:buffer count:len];
}
```

Additionally, `NSDictionary` is an *un-ordered* container, so your `-objectAtIndex:` method makes no sense.